# how to delete from mysql multiple rows depending on other rows in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table Called phones contains all members phone numbers each member has unique id and there is another table called posts the posts table has many rows each post has its member id and another cells

I need to collect all members IDs from the posts table depending on the branches cell and delete from phones table where the members ids collected from the posts table

I tried this but it give me error message that mysql server lost the connection

```
delete from `phones` where `mid` in(select `uid` from `posts` where `branches` = 'contact');
```

Note: I'm using mysql workbench with my local server

**UPDATED**

this query also worked after I setup the Preferences below

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor and increase the parameter: DBMS connection read time out (in seconds). For instance: 86400.

Close and reopen MySQL Workbench. Kill your previously query that probably is running and run the query again.

Thanks to @scaisEdge

Comment: Query is correct, not sure why connection is being lost.  Are these huge tables? if so probably the select query is taking too long due to lack of an index on `branches`?

Comment: the tables are huge and branches column dose not have index

Comment: @mohamad, you are beating around the bushes. If the table is huge and no  index on `branches`, the entire table will be scanned and depending on the hardware and resources available to MySQL, it may take much longer than DB connection timeout.  Have the indexes, your query is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query seems correct  .. anyway you can try with a inner join

```
delete  `phones`.*
from `phones` 
inner join `posts`  on `phones`.`mid`  = `posts`.`uid` 
        and `posts`.`branches` = 'contact'
```

the inner join don't use a IN clause so you can bypass the involved  limitation

if the error persist  try increment the read time out

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor and icrease the parameter: DBMS connection read time out (in seconds). For instance: 86400.

Close and reopen MySQL Workbench. Kill your previously query that probably is running and run the query again.

Comment: Not sure why this would work and not the one posted in the question?

Comment: @AllenKing   if the number  of elem in IN clause is high you can reach the limit  ..  so inner join avoid this condition

Comment: ok.  My suspicion is that proper indexes are not set.  So even a join is not guaranteed to work. Poor indexes can only be fixed by putting proper indexes on tables :-)

Comment: could be  .. but poor index impact on performance  ..  max_packect_size  . impact on the volume onof  data  involved ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: I also used inner join but it gives me error message

Comment: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: I have update the code with the suggestion for read time increase

Comment: @scaisEdge it seems working fine but it will take long time as the tables are huge .. thanks for help now i'm waiting the query to finish :)

Comment: Do the fact your query work .. take a look for a proper index setting so .. you can reduce the elab time ..